# pass property between viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf

I went through similar questions but I didn't find a answer that fits my code. I'm trying to pass data(the client type Id) with WPF from a view Model called Client to a View Model Named Line (every client has multiple lines so the line I Enter should know which client is the owner)

update: the AddCommand

this is the Client Code:

```
public class CRMClientViewModel : BaseViewModel
{

    static string currentClient;


    public Command AddLineCommand { get; set; }

    public CRMClientViewModel(object obj)
    {

        AddLineCommand = new Command(OnAddLineCommand);
    }
    void OnAddLineCommand(object obj)
    {
        MainWindowViewModel.Instance.ShowCRMClient = false;
        MainWindowViewModel.Instance.ShowCRMLine = true;

    }

    private string _clientId;

    public string ClientId
    {
        get { return _clientId; }
        set
        {
            _clientId = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            currentClient = value;
        }
    }






}
}
```

the Base View Model contains:

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

}
```

this is the xaml of the Client View:

```
  <UserControl x:Class="DiamondCellular.View.CRMClientView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:DiamondCellular.View.ViewModels"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DiamondCellular.View"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Height="350" Width="525" FontSize="18" Background="White">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <ViewModel:CRMClientViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>




        <Button x:Name ="Add" Content="AddLine" Command ="{Binding AddLineCommand}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="6" Foreground="#FFFF0012" Margin="0,10.4,17.8,9.8" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="12" Width="71"/>



</UserControl>
```

I'm trying to pass the client Id I get From the Client view to the Line View Model

Comment: The `CRMClientViewModel` maintains a reference (i.e. property or ObservableCollection) to the Line ViewModel?

Comment: What is the code for `AddLineCommand`?

Comment: Fer Garcia - They are in the same namespace, if you mean a mutual property so no, they only have a shared BaseViewModel

Comment: Please edit code into the question, not as comment. This doesn't look like it is actually adding a line. So how is the line added in the end?

Comment: @Ilanz, well, I think your ViewModel needs such a reference; i.e. what if there's not instance of that class? (even when they share namespace). Or, are you using a service locator or similar technique? I agree with grek40, you need to show more of your code.

Comment: I put you all the code, (I didn't want to overflow you with data)

Comment: Woah, take it slowly... before, you provided not enough information, now you are pushing everything onto us*. How about YOU do the work of extracting exactly the code and xaml that is involved in adding a line? (*) Not really everything... what is `Line` and where is a line created?

Comment: the code runs, so I thought you might want to see it, nevertheless, i gave you only the specific line

Comment: Use `CommandParameter={Binding Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}` to pass the viewmodel to the command (but then you will also need to give your viewmodel a name (or don't refer to the static resource and just use `{Binding}`)

Comment: @Icepickle you dont need a `CommandParameter`at all. You "call" the command in the corresponding viewModel already...

Comment: Thank you all, I have Found  The Answer, Should I delete The question?

Comment: No you shouldn't, you should mark the correct answer (in case none was given that fitted your question, you can self answer your question and mark that one as an answer). Deleting the question doesn't help anybody else with a potential similar question as yours. @Mat it can always help to separate some of these things a bit better, something wpf is normally quite good at :)

Comment: Keep the question or delete it... for me it depends on, whether the answer is actually related to the question. If your solution is in some code part that was never included in the question, then be sure to write an answer where this is reflected. If it's actually hard work to relete the answer to the question, then deleting might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right you want to have a classical Master-Detail-view aka parent-child.

You can pass the "parent" to your "child" in the constructor.

```
void OnAddLineCommand(object obj)
{
//...
var lineVM = new LineViewModel(this);
this.Lines.Add(lineVM);
//...
}
```

I assume that you want to work with the lines of a client (whatever that is). You need a Property which holds the `Line`s

```
public ObservableCollection<LineViewModel>{get;}
```

when saving the parent (in your case `Client`) you save also all children.

Answer (score 0):

This is What I Finally Did:

Created An Repository Class
in which I put a singelton to Init it only once and all the view Models Can get Access
:

```
 public class UIRepository
 {
    private static volatile UIRepository instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    private UIRepository(){}
    public static UIRepository Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new UIRepository();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }

    private string _currentClientId;

    public string CurrentClientId
    {
        get { return _currentClientId; }
        set { _currentClientId = value; }
    }}
```

in the Client ViewModel Class in the property clientId(which has a binding in the xaml) I enter The new clientId

```
    private string _clientId;

    public string ClientId
    {
        get { return _clientId; }
        set
        {
            _clientId = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
            UIRepository.Instance.CurrentClientId = ClientId;
        }
    }
```

Then I Added a Command in the Client Class that Enters the clientId When I Change to The new View(by using Binding On The Visibility Property:

```
    private void OnAddLineCommand(object obj)
    {
        MainWindowViewModel.Instance.ShowCRMClient = false;
        MainWindowViewModel.Instance.ShowCRMLine = true;

        UIRepository.Instance.CurrentClientId = ClientId;

    }
```

Thats all